# Quaternion that is not complex

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, quaternions

So I have a question which is asking for a Quaternion which is not complex. I'm supposed to find this number on the Internet and we never got introduced to it. Could someobdy give me some kind of hint for what I should be searching for ?

Comment: Consider adding a tag for a broader subject area to which the question belongs. This will improve the visibility of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you view the complex numbers inside the quaternions.

If you view the complex numbers as the span of 1 and $i$ insider the quaternions, then $j$ is not in that set, so it should be an example for you.